# Drupal 6: Creating form to create node..!

Tags: drupal, form-api

I am creating a custom form with 4 fields & I want to create a node of a particular content type, which is having some CCK fields.

I am intended to create node pro-grammatically on submission of this form. I have plan to push default values for some fields and some fields will be mapped with this form widgets..

Here is my code

```
 <?php

require 'modules/node/node.pages.inc';

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */

function taskform_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/content/taskform'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Task',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('taskform_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('create create_task content'),
  ); 
  return $items;
}
 global $user;

function taskform_perm() {
  return array('Submit daily task');
}

function taskform_form(&$node)
{


  $form['date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date', 
    '#title' => t('Date'),        
  );

  $form['edproject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('Project'), 

    '#options' => array(
      1 => 'Konnected', 
      2 => 'eLearning', 
      3 => 'Others',
    ),
    '#description' => t('Choose a project'),
  );

  $form['task'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Task'), 
    '#size' => 30,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    '#description' => t('Enter the task'),
  );

  $form['remarks'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Remarks'), 
    '#size' => 30,
    '#description' => t('Enter remarks (If any).'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add Task'),
    '#submit' => array('taskform_form_submit'),
  );
  return $form;

}

function taskform_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'create_task';
  $node->uid = $user->uid;
  $node->title = $form_state['values']['task'];
  $node->body = $form_state['values']['task'];
  $node->status = 1;
  $node->promote = 0;
  $node->field_assigned_uid[]['uid'] = $user->uid;
  node_object_prepare($node);
    $node = node_submit($node);
    if ($node->validated) {
        node_save($node);
    }
    else{
        t("Node not created");
    }


}
```

Now when I am submitting this, It's creating the content type with the text-field text as title & body which I am intended to do...but I want to store UID(logged in user ID) in uid column of the table node...and I have tried doing it as you can see...but still it's sending 0... 
I need help on this...please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it's not a too good idea to make a node for each webform submission. Lame. 
You can always tailor node form to do what webform does so it's a straight forward setup. Also, you can access each submission's data easily, and webform already has Views integration so I don't know why you need to create a node.

However, if you still need to go ahead, the best way I'd suggest is using webform's new hooks (since Webform 3). 
See [hook_webform_submission_insert](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7)

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
// print the submitted values object's information as a message.
// Once you have grabbed the necessary data, remove this line. 
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($submission, TRUE).'</pre>');

// Now, grab the fields you want and map them to the $node object below.
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title   = 'Webform submission: '$submission->sid;
$node->body    = 'test body';
$node->type    = 'story';
$node->created = time();
$node->status  = 1; //published.
$node->promote = 1; 
$node->sticky  = 0;
$node->format  = 1;
$node->uid     = 1; // author!

if ($node = node_submit($node)) {
  node_save($node);
}
else {
  // error creating node. 
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response.
I have some question..I tried making form with help of formAPI and submit values through node_save().
I am not successful in mapping the values of input data of the user to the node table with this function but this function is just crating node with blanks field.
Now as you have suggested me this...I can try to do it by the help of webform hook but the question is..how to create form widget by code by help of this hook?
Or please suggest me where to put this code after making a webform from interface..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you need to use webform? It seems like you'd have more control and less issues by creating a specific content type for this and giving permission to anonymous users to submit it. Then, you can get a module that provides field-level permissions and deny access to the fields you don't want them touching (making sure they aren't required).

Am I missing something from what you need?

Comment: Actually I have a content type with some CCK fields..and that is listed in one group. If a user go there and create content by clicking that then I have to show every fields to fill..

But I have to make a a form with just 4 fields, which I will show at some different place and from there I just want to create that previous content quickly...

This is the requirement...was I able to explain ?

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, I'd probably recommend creating the form programmatically (eg: http://www.krlucas.com/blog/2009/07/19/creating-mini-node-entry-form-drupal-6) rather than using Webform, but it seems you're already well into it so best I can do is wish you luck!